# Unrolling javascript loops

Tags: javascript, loop-unrolling

I have a cubic 3D array "class" like this:

```
function Array3D(size) {
    this.data = new Array(size*size*size);
    var makeIndex = function(p) {
        return p[0] + p[1]*size + p[2]*size*size;
    }
    this.get = function(p) { return this.data[makeIndex(p)]; };
    this.set = function(p, value) { this.data[makeIndex(p)] = value; };
}
```

I'd like to generalize to multiple dimensions, but without affecting access performance. Here's my simple approach:

```
function ArrayND(size, N) {
    var s = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) s *= size;
    this.data = new Array(s);

    var makeIndex = function(p) {
        var ind = 0;
        for(var i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
            ind = ind*size + p[i];
        return ind;
    }
    this.get = function(p) { return this.data[makeIndex(p)]; };
    this.set = function(p, value) { this.data[makeIndex(p)] = value; };
}
```

Is there any way I can "unroll" my `makeIndex` function, so that the loop is evaluated once at declaration time, but not upon invokation? Would the overhead of using runtime-generated code from `eval` or `new Function()` cancel out the benefit of not looping?

Both `size` and `N` are essentially constants, so the repeated multiplication and iteration feels like something that could be done only once.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ind += p[i] * Math.pow( size, i );`, resulting in `p[0] + p[i] * size + p[1] * size * size + ...`?

Comment: The only calculation that you can do at declaration is creating the `[0, size, size*size, size*size*size, ...]` array. Multiplying this array with the `p` array and adding it up into a sum, has to be done on each get/set operation.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Sure, but since `size` is a constant, the length of `p` is a constant, so in principle the loop could be unrolled.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your loop performs *better* than the unrolled expression for `N` values larger than 3. The loop performs `N` multiplications, and `N` additions, whereas the unrolled expression performs `N-1` additions, but `N*(N-1)/2` multiplications. For example, for `N=10`, the loop performs 10 multiplications, whereas the unrolled expression performs **45** multiplications. So, I'd say, stick with the loop.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, you'd have to precalculate the constants in addition to unrolling the loop, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method of doing this, that builds the function contents as a string using `new Function`:

```
var makeIndex = (function() {
    var code = []
    var scale = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        code.push("p["+i+"]*"+scale);
        scale *= size;
    }
    return new Function('p', 'return '+code.join('+'));
})();
```

Comment: I think that as long as this isn't the final code you end up using, it better be posted as an edit to the question showing what you tried so far.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Not sure I agree. This is definitely an answer, not part of the question. I'm still hoping on a better answer, but that doesn't make this not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
var makeIndex = (function () {
    var arr = _.range( N ).map(function ( i ) {
        return Math.pow( size, i );
    });

    function dotProduct ( a, b ) {
        var sum = 0;
        for ( var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            sum += a[i] * b[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    return function ( p ) {
        return dotProduct( p, arr );
    };
}());
```

So you create the `[0, size, size*size, size*size*size, ...]` array beforehand, and then on each invocation, you perform a dot product on that array and the `p` array.

I use underscore's [range](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#range) function in my code.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but I'm not sure it buys anything. For  a given value of N, your `makeIndex` does N multiplications, N additions, and an iteration. My initial version does the same thing, but without the overhead of the list.

Comment: Also, +1 for `new Array(N).map(...)` - I've never come across that idiom before.

Comment: Which is probably because `new Array(N).map` always returns an array full of `undefined`s in Chrome.

Comment: @Eric Yes, `new Array(N).map(...)` doesn't work, I just noticed. `new Array(N)` only sets the length of the array, but does not create any elements, so map doesn't run. I'll have to go now, but will get back to this later.

Comment: @Eric Yes indeed, my `arr` array is just unnecessary overhead. Your initial loop is likely the most efficient way to do it with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the traditional approach to multidimensional arrays?

```
function ArrayND(size, N, fill) {
    if (N < 1) throw new Error('Arrays must have at least one dimension.');
    if (size < 1) throw new Error('Arrays must have at least one element.');
    var arr = new Array(size);
    populate(arr, 1);

    function populate(a, depth) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (depth < N) {
                a[i] = new Array(size);
                populate(a[i], depth+1);
            } else a[i]=fill;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

This returns a multidimensional array (optionally filled with a default value) that's much more intuitive to access:

```
var arr = ArrayND(5, 3, 'hi');

console.log(arr[0][1][2]); // => 'hi'
arr[0][1][3] = 'mom';
```

---

**Update:** Since your goal is to access the multidimensional array by giving an argument of arbitrary length, I'd use this approach:

```
!function() {
    function ArrayND(size, N, fill) {
        if (N < 1) throw new Error('Arrays must have at least one dimension.');
        if (size < 1) throw new Error('Arrays must have at least one element.');
        if (!(this instanceof ArrayND)) return new ArrayND(size, N, fill); // allow this ctor to be called without `new` operator

        var arr = this;
        arr.length = size;
        populate(arr, 1);

        function populate(a, depth) {
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (depth < N) {
                    a[i] = new Array(size);
                    populate(a[i], depth+1);
                } else a[i]=fill;
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }

    var proto = Object.create(Array.prototype); // polyfill necessary for older browsers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill

    proto.get = function(indicies) {
        var pos = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < indicies.length; i++) {
            pos = pos[indicies[i]];
        }
        return pos;
    };
    proto.set = function(indicies, value) {
        var pos = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < indicies.length - 1; i++) {
            pos = pos[indicies[i]];
        }
        pos[indicies[indicies.length-1]] = value;
    }
    ArrayND.prototype = proto;

    this.ArrayND = ArrayND; // export to global scope
}();
```

This gives you the best of both worlds: a `new ArrayND(s, d)` still looks and behaves like a normal array, but also gives you `get` and `set` accessors that can take an arbitrary number of index arguments at runtime – all without modifying the builtin `Array`.

```
var arr = new ArrayND(5, 3, 'hi');

console.log(arr[0][1][2]); // => hi
console.log(arr.get([0,1,2]); // => hi

arr.push([]); // => 6 (the new length)
arr.set([6,0], 'I was added');
```

Comment: I'm implementing it as I am because it means I my program can generalize to more dimensions. I can invoke `arr.get(l)` with a list of any size at runtime, but I can't do `arr[l[0]][l[1]]...`