# Any way to force js engines to unroll a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, v8

I have a performance critical queue container that does a lot of random inserts/deletes. In my container class, I have a fixed size Uint32Array called updates and in my insert logic, I need to compare a value to every value in this update array.

Originally, I did it simply like this:

```
const u = this.updates;
for (let i = 0; i < u.length; i++) bucket_offset += bi >= u[i];
```

Then, just as I was putting finishing touches on the container and just screwing around, I tried unrolling said loop

```
const u = this.updates;
bucket_offset += (bi >= u[0]) + (bi >= u[1]) + (bi >= u[2]) + (bi >= u[3]) + (bi >= u[4]) + (bi >= u[5]) + (bi >= u[6]) + (bi >= u[7]) + (bi >= u[8]) + (bi >= u[9]) + (bi >= u[10]) + (bi >= u[11]) + (bi >= u[12]) + (bi >= u[13]) + (bi >= u[14]) + (bi >= u[15]);
```

And turns out this is around 10x faster on chrome, making the whole insert ~30% faster.

After that revelation, I'm looking for a way to make the VM understand that its okay to unroll that loop, after all, this.updates.length is a constant.

At the end of the day, it can stay the way it is but I'd prefer a loop since it would just look nicer. Any ideas?

My main target is the Chrome browser running on V8.

Comment: How does `for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)` perform?

Comment: These optimizations are engine specific, so which engine are you optimizing for?

Comment: Any luck here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669910/unrolling-javascript-loops

Comment: Is that loop equivalent to `bucket_offset + = u.filter(y => y < bi).length` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms I think you meant 16, but it performs the same as .length. This is 99% meant to run in the chrome browser (as a part of a game), even though I do look at other browsers, their performance for this and various other algorithms I use is.. disappointing so for now I'm just focusing on chrome.

Comment: @Eineki it is equivalent to y => bi >= y, also I did try out its performance and its worse than the loop

Comment: @jmrk wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66082249/367865). Maybe they have an idea as to why manually unrolling this loop results in much faster execution and why the engine either isn't unrolling the loop or is unrolling the loop but getting results slower than the manually unrolled version.

Comment: From the duplicate, it seems as V8 did not unroll loops in 2021, so if nothing changed dramatically the answer is probably _no_. It surprised my though, thought V8 would unroll, at least in trivial cases ....

Comment: Since you are creating the `Uint32Array` you know its length. Loop over the same constant you passed to the `Uint32Array` constructor.

Comment: @JonasWilms the answer on the duplicate states that "*we currently have an ongoing project to unroll more loops; […] we're still fine-tuning the heuristics for when it should kick in*". So it might actually be worth following up what came out of that project, and maybe to report a bug that the heuristics should detect this particular case.

Comment: @Bergi if I read https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/src/compiler/loop-unrolling.h correctly, then TurboFan unrolls loops with less than 5 iterations, though the commit message suggests it's only available for wasm?

Comment: @bergi jmrk confirmed that this is still WASM only, so the answer stays _no_ (for now).